# PDF vector graphic smaller than the png at same size

Tags: ios, pdf, uiimageview, png, vector-graphics

I converted some SVG images into PDF and png files for my iOS app. When adding them to the UIImageView, the pdf images look smaller than the png equivalent. The scale type was set to center, so no scaling happens at runtime.

btw, the pdf and png look the same when I open them in preview and adobe reader

Anyone had same issue and got a solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

When converting an SVG to PDF, make sure the DPI is set to **72**. That way, the size will match with the PNG resource that you have. Xcode actually expects vector-based resources to be **1x** in size.

Comment: Thanks the4kman. Could you recommend a good svg to pdf conversion app or website?

Comment: Check out Inkscape, CloudConvert or Zamzar.

Comment: my svg files doesn't display correctly in inkscape on Mac.
I didn't find a way to set dpi in CouldConvert. Actually, the pdf files, which were smaller than png, were converted on CouldConvert.